# Some alignment issues in the align environment

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align

I have searched along in this site and in other places and I am left with some questions.

So here is my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\left( \dfrac{d^2\overrightarrow{OM}}{dt^2} \right)_{\mathcal{R}_A}
    &= \left( \dfrac{d^2\overrightarrow{OO'}}{dt^2} \right)_{\mathcal{R}_A} +\left( \dfrac{d^2\overrightarrow{O'M}}{dt^2} \right)_{\mathcal{R}_A} \\
    &= \overrightarrow{a_a}(O') + \left( \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2}  \left( x' \overrightarrow{u'_x}+y' \overrightarrow{u'_y}+z' \overrightarrow{u'_z} \right)  \right) \\
    &= \overrightarrow{a_a}(O') + x'\left( \dfrac{d^2 \overrightarrow{u'_x} }{dt^2} \right)_{\mathcal{R}_A}+ 2 \dot{x} \left( \dfrac{d \overrightarrow{u'_x} }{dt} \right)_{\mathcal{R}_A} + \ddot{x}'\overrightarrow{u'_x} \\
    &\mathrel{\hphantom{= \overrightarrow{a_a}(O') }} +\, y'\left( \dfrac{d^2 \overrightarrow{u'_y} }{dt^2} \right)_{\mathcal{R}_A}+ 2 \dot{y} \left( \dfrac{d \overrightarrow{u'_y} }{dt} \right)_{\mathcal{R}_A} + \ddot{y}'\overrightarrow{u'_y} \\
    & \mathrel{\hphantom{= \overrightarrow{a_a}(O') }} +\, z'\left( \dfrac{d^2 \overrightarrow{u'_z} }{dt^2} \right)_{\mathcal{R}_A}+ 2 \dot{z} \left( \dfrac{d \overrightarrow{u'_z} }{dt} \right)_{\mathcal{R}_A} + \ddot{z}'\overrightarrow{u'_z} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

And here is my result with some painted lines 
[image]

So I have some questions about alignment that turn around the point that with the `\mathrel{\hphantom}`, I somewhat managed to align my first + '(although it seems there is a tiny misalignment, if someone has a suggestion I am happy with it), but the next terms nevertheless do not align themselves. Why is that so ? And it seems worst for my third line, that seems it self not to be aligned with the second one.
Among these lines, why did I have to add a `\,` after my first displayed + of the lines, although it is already taken into account in the first line ?

Comment: the reason for the misalignment is the very slight difference in width of the x, y, and z.  the answers with `align[ed]at*` are the best approach here.

Comment: I had thought about that, but the result I obtain would mean that x is slightly wider than y, that sound very strange doesn't it ?

Comment: it wouldn't be too surprising to me to find that these letters really do have slightly different widths.  i will check that tomorrow, when i can look at my copy of volume e of *computers & typesetting*, which contains the drawing instructions for all the cm fonts.  (an alternate method of checking would be to run `tftopl` on the file `cmmi10.tfm`, to get a human-readable version of the metrics.)

Comment: The idea itself does not seem incredible to me, but my interrogation was more that I would believe that y would be larger than z or x, from a very naive standpoint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution without `\hphantom`, but with `alignat*`. I took the opportunity to improve the look of the vectors with the `esvect` package, and simplified the code for the derivatives with the `esdiff` package: it has a `\diff*` command, with an optional argument (the order of derivation) and $3$ mandatory arguments: the function to derive, the name of the variable and the point at which the derivative is evaluated. A similar `diffp*` command exists for partial derivatives.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools, esvect}%
 \usepackage{esdiff}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
 \diff*{\vv{OM}}{t}{\mathcal{R}_A}
    &=\mathrlap{\diff*[2]{\vv{OO'}}{t}{\mathcal{R}_A}+\diff*[2]{\vv{O'M}}{t}{\mathcal{R}_A}} \\
    &=\vv{a_a}(O') & & + \mathrlap{\diff[2]{}{t} \Bigl( x' \vv{u'_x}+y' \vv{u'_y}+z' \vv{u'_z} \Bigr)} \\
    & & & + x'\diff*[2]{\vv{u'_x}}{t}{\mathcal{R}_A} & & + 2 \dot{x} \diff*{\vv{u'_x} }{t}{\mathcal{R}_A} && + \ddot{x}'\vv{u'_x} \\
    & & & + y'\diff*[2]{\vv{u'_y}}{t}{\mathcal{R}_A} & & + 2 \dot{y}\diff*{\vv{u'_y}}{t}{\mathcal{R}_A} & &+ \ddot{y}'\vv{u'_y} \\
    & & &+ z'\diff*[2]{\vv{u'_z}}{t}{\mathcal{R}_A} & & + 2 \dot{z}\diff*{\vv{u'_z}}{t}{\mathcal{R}_A} & & + \ddot{z}'\vv{u'_z}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is both great and slightly annoying, as you make me rewrite my whole code as your solution is by far better `:)`.  Thanks for the tips, these arrows are magnificent

Answer (score 5):

Split the \hphantom, so that only the equal sign is in the \mathrel:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x   &= \overrightarrow{a_a}(O') + x'\\
    &\mathrel{\hphantom{= \overrightarrow{a_a}(O') }} +\, y'\\
    &\mathrel{\hphantom{=}} \hphantom{\overrightarrow{a_a}(O')} + y'\\
    &\mathrel{\hphantom{=}} \hphantom{\overrightarrow{a_a}(O')} \tikz[overlay]\draw[red](6pt,0)--++(0,3);+ z'
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate a bit on why is this so, so that I can at best understand it, or at least know what to put in a `\mathrel` or not the next time I encounter such a thing. Additionnaly, the other + signs, are not aligned, is this 'normal' in the sens only due to differences in sizes of `x`, `y` and `z ` ?

Comment: Only the equal sign is a relation symbol, so you should only put it (or its phantom) in a \mathrel.  If you want to align the following plus symbols too you should use a nested aligned or alignedat as suggested by campa, doing it with \hphantom would be rather painful.